# Shape detection with opencv/python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to teach my test automation framework to detect a selected item in an app using opencv (the framework grabs frames/screenshots from the device under test). Selected items are always a certain size and always have blue border which helps but they contain different thumbnail images. See the example image provided.

I have done a lot of Googling and reading on the topic and I'm close to getting it to work expect for one scenario which is image C in the example image. [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbclA.png) This is where there is a play symbol on the selected item.

My theory is that OpenCV gets confused in this case because the play symbol is basically circle with a triangle in it and I'm asking it to find a rectangular shape.

I found this to be very helpful: https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/

My code looks like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = "testimg.png"

values = {"min threshold": {"large": 10, "small": 1},
          "max threshold": {"large": 200, "small": 800},
          "min area": {"large": 75000, "small": 100},
          "max area": {"large": 80000, "small": 1000},
          "min circularity": {"large": 0.7, "small": 0.60},
          "max circularity": {"large": 0.82, "small": 63},
          "min convexity": {"large": 0.87, "small": 0.87},
          "min inertia ratio": {"large": 0.01, "small": 0.01}}
size = "large"

# Read image
im = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = values["min threshold"][size]
params.maxThreshold = values["max threshold"][size]

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = values["min area"][size]
params.maxArea = values["max area"][size]

# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = values["min circularity"][size]
params.maxCircularity = values["max circularity"][size]


# Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = False
params.minConvexity = values["min convexity"][size]

# Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = False
params.minInertiaRatio = values["min inertia ratio"][size]

# Create a detector with the parameters
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)

for k in keypoints:
    print k.pt
    print k.size

# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures
# the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob   
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255),
                                      cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show blobs
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

How do I get OpenCV to only look at the outer shape defined by the blue border and ignore the inner shapes (the play symbol and of course the thumbnail image)? I'm sure it must be do-able somehow.

Comment: I have an additional question. What if there is no border around the image? Is there any way of just detecting a thumbnail image with slightly rounded corners against a white background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I toyed around with this a bit more after reading your suggestions and found that blob detection is not the way to go. Using color recognition to find the contours solved the issue however as was suggested above. Thanks again!

My solution looks like this:

```
frame = cv2.imread("image.png")
color = ((200, 145, 0), (255, 200, 50))
lower_color = numpy.array(color[0], dtype="uint8")
upper_color = numpy.array(color[1], dtype="uint8")

# Look for the color in the frame and identify contours
color = cv2.GaussianBlur(cv2.inRange(frame, lower_color, upper_color), (3, 3), 0)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(color.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

if contours:

    for c in contours:
        rectangle = numpy.int32(cv2.cv.BoxPoints(cv2.minAreaRect(c)))

        # Draw a rectangular frame around the detected object
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [rectangle], -1, (0, 0, 255), 4)

    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many different techniques, that will do the job. I am not really sure how BlobDetector works, so I took anoter approach. Also I am not really sure what you need, but you can modify this solution for your needs.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_name = "CbclA.png" #Image you have provided

min_color = 150 #Color you are interested in (from green channel)
max_color = 170

min_size = 4000 #Size of border you are interested in (number of pixels)
max_size = 30000


img_rgb = cv2.imread(img_name)
img = img_rgb[:,:,1] #Extract green channel
img_filtered = np.bitwise_and(img>min_color, img < max_color) #Get only colors of your border


nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img_filtered.astype(np.uint8))

good_area_index = np.where(np.logical_and(stats[:,4] > min_size,stats[:,4] < max_size)) #Filter only areas we are interested in

for area in stats[good_area_index] : #Draw it
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, (area[0],area[1]), (area[0] + area[2],area[1] + area[3]), (0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imwrite('result.png',img_rgb)
```

Take a look at documentation of [connectedComponentsWithStats](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#connectedcomponents)

Note: I am using Python 3

[image: result - red rectangles around detected areas]

Edit: result image added

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want a rectangle bounding the blue box with curved edges. If this is the case, it's very easy.
Apply this -

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 200) # You'll have to tune these

# Find contours

(_, contour, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
# This should return only one contour in 'contour' in your case
```

This should do but if you still get a contour (the bounding box) with curved edges apply this -

```
rect = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True) 
# Play with the second parameter, appropriate range would be from 1% to 5%
```